# Consultas con laravel y eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5

Buen día, estoy comenzando con **laravel** y desarrollo una página para practicar.

Tengo estos dos modelos:

```
class Personas extends Model{

      protected $table = 'persona';
      protected $primaryKey = 'id';
      public $timestamps = false;
      protected $fillable = [
                 'nombre',
                 'apellido', 
                 'dni', 
                 'direccion'
               ];
      public function empleado(){

          return $this->hasOne('Practica\Models\Empleado', 'id_persona', 'id');
      }
}


class Empleado extends Model{

       protected $table = 'empleados';
       protected $primaryKey = 'id_persona';
       public $timestamps = false;
       protected $fillable = [
                 'id_persona',
                 'id_cargo', 
                 'sueldo',
                 'ficha'
               ];
       public function persona(){
          return $this->belongsTo('Practica\Models\Persona', 'id_persona', 'id');
       }
}
```

Tengo personas que son empleados y también clientes, pero en este momento deseo obtener a todas las personas que son clientes.

¿Cómo se podría realizar esta consulta usando **eloquent** orm de **laravel**?

Comment: En tu modelo de datos, ¿Que es "cliente"? ¿Es otro modelo similar a Empleado?

Comment: Esos dos modelos estan relacionados? de ser asi es con un simple JOIN

Comment: ¿dónde están los clientes?

Answer (score 1):

A continuación tienes un ejemplo de como puedes hacerlo:

```
$persona= Persona:find(1);

$empleados = $empleados->empleados()->whereHas('id_persona', function($q){
    $q->where('id', $persona->id);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta desde un controlador sería algo como:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $clientes= new App\Clientes::orderBy('id','ASC');
    dd($clientes->personas);      
}
```

Pero estas partiendo de un mal diseño. Ahí vinculas los clientes con sus personas nada más.